# getValue formatting is off when pulling a date from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script to convert a spreadsheet to a PDF.

To define the title of the PDF, I'm pulling in data from a few specific cells, one of which contains a date. The problem is, the date comes out in a long format in the title. Here's a chunk of my code:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"); //       Opens spreadsheet to pull name from, by ID.
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PurchaseOrderForm'); // Sets the sheet
  var ponumber = sheet.getRange("G3:G3"); // Define ranges/cells here + below.
  var date = sheet.getRange("G2:G2") // Custom cell to pull from
  var companyname = sheet.getRange("A11:A11") // These are then added together in line 30

  var name = ponumber.getValue()+" | "+date.getValue()+" | "+companyname.getValue()+".pdf"; // Output of the final PDF name. A composition of the above vars, plus some custom text.
```

This creates the PDF name almost as I want it, except for the date part. This is an example of the PDF titles I get:

```
14PO051 | Tue Jan 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT) | Micronclean.pdf
```

The date comes out, but not in a format I want/need. In the spreadsheet the date cell, G2, is formatted DD/MM/YY. I need something like this to come out in my title, otherwise it's just too long to be of any use.

If anyone knows how to get it down to DD/MM/YY or equivalent, I'd be grateful to know!

One workaround would be to not have the dates formatted, and just manually input them into the spreadsheet. I hope it doesn't come to that, my colleagues like not having to type the whole thing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange("G2:G2").getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY");
```

?

Comment: This works and is extremely useful. For people looking at this in the future, yes, it is possible to format the date as you please (I went for DD.MM.YY just to have it look like our previous docs).

Comment: Just a fix: as stated here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate%28Date,String,String%29) `formatDate()` use `SimpleDateFormat` formats, you can see them here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html . Please note: **DD is number of day in the year**, so you should modify the code to usea lower case day formats: `dd`

Comment: are you saying to adjust the timezone source too or just DD?

Comment: @BryanP I believe it's simply referring to the SimpleDateFormat needing a lowercase `dd`. You can also adjust timezones using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 5):

To get the values from the sheet as they appear (using sheet formatting), use getDisplayValue or getDisplayValues

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues

(use the plural function anytime you're getting more than 1 cell, if possible; batch ops are faster!)